# Django Session works in localhost but not in remote server

Tags: django, apache, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-sessions

I have set a session value during my login view upon successful user authentication. However, this session value is returning None in another view while i am trying to access it(The same code works in my local environment)

`login_view`

```
@csrf_excempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_view(request):
    # Authenticate user - upon success authentication
    request.session['username'] = username

    # Able to print the stored session value here as well
    print(request.session.get('username'))

    **Redirect to landing.html**


Once the user is authenticated and the landing page is loaded upon session check.

def index(request):
    print("the session value is : ", request.session.get('username')) #this returns None
    if request.session.get('username')
       return render(request, 'landing.html') # if session present, render the landing.html page
    else:
       return render(request, 'auth.html') #if session not present, reload the login page again
```

what am i missing here? I tried a lot to debug, but to no avail.

while running in my local environment, i can see the cookies in the browser while i inspect the page, but it is not the case while i run it over my apache server.

Also, i am using file based sessions and i have set the SESSION_ENGINE and SESSION_FILE_PATH accordingly.

I also tried looking at similar questions already being asked on the same, but i did not find a general answer to this, and i have tried all those solutions as well.

Would appreciate if someone can explain the process of how the django can achieve session functionality on the apache server.

Thank You!!

Comment: Can you check /tmp folder for cookie files. I think there might be a permission problem. In django's official documentation, it says "Be sure to check that your web server has permissions to read and write to this location."

Comment: I have set my SESSION_FILE_PATH as follows.
SESSION_FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR/ 'sessions'
and everytime i am saving the username into the session in my login view the session files are getting saved in the sessions folder.
what i noticed is that, in my local, as soon as the session is saved, a session_ID cookie is created, which i confirmed by inspecting the page. the only difference between the local and production environment would be that, while saving the session value in prod, the cookie is not created in the browser. Might this be a problem?

Also any suggestions how i can resolve this?

Comment: -rw------- 1 apache apache 111 Mar 24 06:38 sessionid4fsomerandomalphanumericvalue.

This is an example of the session file created in the 'sessions' folder.